# In Ionic android, background mode geolocation is not working

Tags: geolocation, ionic3

As per the documentation in Ionic website, background geolocation is not working when app goes to background. Kindly help to resolve this issue.

**Ionic 3 Code:**

```
const config: BackgroundGeolocationConfig = {
      desiredAccuracy: 0,
      stopOnStillActivity:false,
      stationaryRadius: 20,
      distanceFilter: 5,
      debug: false,
      interval: 3000,
      stopOnTerminate: false,
};


this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config).subscribe((location: BackgroundGeolocationResponse) => {
    console.log(location);
});
```

**Plugin Used:**
cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation

**Ionic Documentation Link:**
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-geolocation/